# using delegates within a structure does not modify the structures internal elements

Tags: .net, delegates, structure

We thought this would be an easy way to get around the stucture pass by value limitation (in real life our structure has many more members) but we've noticed that using delegates inside a structure does not modify the structures internal members, even if that is the sole purpose of the delegate array.
Given this delegate and a structure:

```
public delegate void ChangeValues();

structure Effects
{
    int val1,val2,val3;

    void SetValues(int index)
    {
        ChangeValues[] delegateArray = new ChangeValues(){this.SetValSet1,this.setValSet2,this.SetValSet3};
        delegateArray[index]();  //now set the values as necessary
    }
    void setValSet1()
    {
        val1=0;val2=1;val3=2;
    }        
    void setValSet2()
    {
        val1=1;val2=2;val3=3;
    }        
    void setValSet3()
    {
        val1=2;val2=3;val3=4;
    }        
}

Effects effects = new Effects();
effects.SetValues(1);    //when stepping through code one sees the values change inside eh setValues functions, but the modified values are gone after leaving this function
```

Does using delegates cause another instance of the structure to be created and then lost?

Answer (score 1):

First: please don't post code that doesn't even compile (unless you're asking why it doesn't compile). It just wastes our time.

Second: yes delegates seem to be value copying for structs, not sure of the specifics, but the following would be a solution:

```
public delegate void ChangeValues(ref Effects a);

public struct Effects
{
    int val1,val2,val3;

    public void SetValues(int index)
    {
        ChangeValues[] delegateArray = new ChangeValues[]{setValSet1,setValSet2,setValSet3};
        delegateArray[index](ref this);  //now set the values as necessary
    }
    public void setValSet1(ref Effects a)
    {
        a.val1 = 0; a.val2 = 1; a.val3 = 2;
    }
    public void setValSet2(ref Effects a)
    {
        a.val1 = 1; a.val2 = 2; a.val3 = 3;
    }
    public void setValSet3(ref Effects a)
    {
        a.val1 = 2; a.val2 = 3; a.val3 = 4;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return val1 + "," + val2 + "," + val3;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Effects effects = new Effects();
        Effects effects2 = new Effects();
        effects.SetValues(1);    //when stepping through code one sees the values change inside eh setValues functions, but the modified values are gone after leaving this function
        Console.WriteLine(effects);
    }
}
```

It outputs: 1,2,3